# index/clustered-index structuring in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, optimization

i am running this report:

```
use SalesDWH
go
;with
cte_biggie as(
select (c.npi+'|'+ CAST(DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) as varchar) +'|'+ 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 01 THEN 'Jan' 
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 02 THEN 'Feb'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 03 THEN 'Mar'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 04 THEN 'Apr'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 05 THEN 'May'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 06 THEN 'Jun'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 07 THEN 'Jul'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 08 THEN 'Aug'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 09 THEN 'Sep'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 10 THEN 'Oct'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 11 THEN 'Nov'
           WHEN DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) = 12 THEN 'Dec'
           END
           +'|'+isnull(cast(COUNT([specimen id]) as varchar),'') +'|'+isnull([practice name],'')+'|'+isnull(b.[mlis practice id],'')+'|'+a.[practice code]+'|'+[Requesting Physician]+'|'+isnull(c.salesrep,'')+'|'+
    isnull(cast(c.dateestablished as varchar),'')+'|'+ ISNULL (c.practiceaddress1,'')+'|'+ISNULL ( c.practiceaddress2 , '' )+'|'+ISNULL (c.practicecity,'')+'|'+ISNULL (c.practicestate,'')+'|'+
    ISNULL(b.[Active Inactive],'')) [result]
from quicklabdump a
    inner join qlmlismapping b
    on (b.[practice code] = a.[practice code])
    inner join PracticeandPhysician c
    on (a.[Requesting Physician]=c.doctorfirstname+' '+c.DOCTORLASTNAME
        and a.[practice code]=c.practicecode)
where   DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]) in (2010,2011)
    and DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]) in (01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12)

group by DATEPART(yy, [DATE entered]), DATEPART(mm, [DATE entered]), a.[practice name],b.[mlis practice id],a.[practice code],
    a.[Requesting Physician],c.salesrep,c.dateestablished, c.practicecity,c.practicestate,c.npi,c.practiceaddress1 ,c.practiceaddress2,
    b.[Active Inactive]


)
select 'NPI|Year Entered|Month Entered|Count|Practice Name|MLIS Code|Practice Code|Physician|Sales Rep|Date Established|Address|Address2|City|State|Status'
union all
select * from cte_biggie
```

since i am joining 3 tables, i would like to know what is best way to optimize this query using indexes and clustered indexes.

on which columns would i add indexes?

currently this report takes 20 seconds. the database is about 5 gigs.

Comment: Assuming you already have clustered indices, I would just make sure to have an index on all foreign key columns involved in your query, as well as the `Date_Entered` column used in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: @marc_s  thanks so much., i do not have the clustered indices, where would i put them?

Comment: @marc_s after setting the clustered index, does it take a while to go into effect?

Comment: You should replace that case statement for the month abbreviation with `left(datename(m, [DATE entered]), 3)`.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson i just did what you said and for some reason it is returning 4x the amount of records!! any idea why?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson the thing is i had to add "[date entered]" in the group by and that returned many more records because it de-aggregated them

Comment: @marc_s what are your thoughts?

Comment: @I__ Replace `[DATE entered]` in your `GROUP BY` with `left(datename(m, [DATE entered]), 3)`.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson thank you!!!! looks like the CASE statement works 15 sec faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is change the WHERE clause - currently, it's not sargable, which means even if there is an index on the Date Entered column, it won't be used because you are using the DATEPART function on it.

Instead, do:

```
WHERE [Date Entered] >= '20100101' AND [Date Entered] < '20120101'
```

That'd be the 1st thing I'd change, and ensure there is an index on Date Entered. This *could* be a good contender as a clustered index, though choosing the best index strategy for your whole environment is difficult without knowing more about data access/loading patterns etc.

Other initial things to check, are about having indices on the fields in other tables involved in the joins.

Comment: @adathdev, i did EXACTLY what you said and the query took 34seconds instead of 20 seconds! what did i do wrong?

Comment: after setting the clustered index, does it take a while to go into effect?

Comment: @l__ - performance tuning can be a bit of a dark art, and is often an iterative/investigative process. So without more information it's difficult to answer! Did you create it as a clustered index, or a nonclustered index? Can you look at the execution plan and look at where most of the time is being taken? Also, just run the query a couple of times just to make sure it is consistently higher.

Comment: bottle neck is here [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Date Entered, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Practice Name, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Practice Code, [SalesDWH].[dbo].[QuickLabDump].Requesting Physician

Comment: does it take a while for the clustered index to take into effect

Comment: @l__ - no. Once the clustered index has been created, it will be available for use straight away.

Comment: thank you. but how is it able to use it right away? doesnt it need to rearrange everything?

Comment: doesnt this imply that it is not instant?" http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/17941/estimate-time-to-create-index

Comment: @l___ = "Once the clustered index has been created" is the key bit of my previous comment. If you created the index via SSMS GUI or executed a bit of SQL to create the index, I'm assuming you waited for it to finish being created before you tried the query - it would have been obvious in either case, when the index finished being created. That link you give is about estimating how long an index will take to be created before actually trying to create it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6413/discussion-between-i-and-adathedev)